# Cookies in HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, sharepoint

I made a stand alone application for authentication against the sharepoint online, I managed to took a token and authentication cookie but, I have a problem with obtaining the Form Digest Value, when i try to obtain the Value from postman i can successfully obtain the value but, when i try to get the value from my code i relieve a java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 for URL: https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo
I google for the problem and check that the errors means that the Context-Length parameter is required i add such parameter with value - 0, but the result was the same.

I will be vary gratefulр if someone had meet the same problem :)
Here is my code

public String getFormDigestValue(List cookies) throws IOException {

```
    URL u = new URL("https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo");
    URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookies.get(2));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookies.get(1));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Origin","xxx.sharepoint.com");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    int c;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
        sb.append((char) (c));
    in.close();
    String result = sb.toString();

    String startTag = "<d:FormDigestValue>";
    String endTag = "</d:FormDigestValue>";

    if(!(result.contains(startTag)) || !(result.contains(endTag))) {
        String errorMessage = "Error during getting form digest value. The form digest value is missing in the response of the request for getting form digest value.";
        throw new IOException(errorMessage);
    } else {
        int startIndex = result.indexOf(startTag, 1);
        int endIndex = result.indexOf(endTag, startIndex + 1);
        String formDigestValue = result.substring(startIndex + startTag.length(), endIndex);

        return formDigestValue;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it was asked 5 month ago, but i put answer for everyone else:

After build your post data:

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
....
....
```

Set post data length in "Content-Length" property:

```
postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
```